# Referencing a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

Given the following object, how would I dynamically access both levels of data?

```
var object = {
    "one": {
        "0": "foo",
        "1": "foo foo",
        "2": "foo foo foo",
        "3": "foo foo foo foo",
        "4": "foo foo foo foo foo"
    },
    "two": {
        "0": "bar",
        "1": "bar bar",
        "2": "bar bar bar",
        "3": "bar bar bar bar",
        "4": "bar bar bar bar bar"
    }
};
```

Shouldn't I be able to do something along the lines of:

```
var outer = "one",
    inner = "3";

console.log(object[outer][inner]);
```

And have the output be "foo foo foo foo"?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Yes that would be the exact output of the code as you have typed it.

Comment: If u r having trouble traversing huge collections / objects, try using underscore/lodash and these util libraries have out of the box methods like pluck(), map() etc. which can be useful .

Comment: Yea this works just fine. What seems to tbe the problem

Comment: For whatever reason, jQuery and my hot reloading were breaking in some spectacular way. I now understand that I am a fool. Thank you all for your comments and helping me to realize it!

Comment: No need to feel foolish - always a chance that someone else may have similar problems in the future and this will set them back on track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
And it does.

`$ cat so2.js
var object = {
  "one": {
    "0": "foo",
    "1": "foo foo",
    "2": "foo foo foo",
    "3": "foo foo foo foo",
    "4": "foo foo foo foo foo"
  },
  "two": {
    "0": "bar",
    "1": "bar bar",
    "2": "bar bar bar",
    "3": "bar bar bar bar",
    "4": "bar bar bar bar bar"
  }
};`

var outer = "one",
  inner = "3";

console.log(object[outer][inner]);

$ node so2.js
foo foo foo foo

Comment: Hot reloading and jQuery weren't playing nice for some reason. It does work, and I am just embarrassed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out using the index, but first you need to get the index of the keys **"one","two"**.
Something like :

```
object[Object.keys(object)[0]][1]     // "foo foo"
object[Object.keys(object)[1]][1]     // "bar bar"
```

Comment: `Object.keys` returns the array of keys for the object and `Object.keys(object)[0]` will return one of the keys, not an index.

Comment: Yes exactly !! I

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for accessing all the values as per your json object :

```
for(var first in object)
{
    for(var second in object[first])
    {
        console.log(object[first][second]);
    }
}
```